# How do I reference the npm packages in _Layout that I installed in my Visual Studio 2017 project?

Tags: npm, dependencies, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I found a few questions that didn't have an answer.

I installed packages, particularly jQuery 3, with npm.  In the Dependencies is has npm and shows jquery, bootstrap, and popper.

How do I use the Javascript in the _Layout.cshtml file?  I don't have them in my wwwroot/lib/dist folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use something like webpack or gulp/grunt to copy the files from `node_modules` into your `wwwroot` directory on build/publish. You can *technically* also just add `node_modules` as a location handled by the static files middleware to allow serving directly from there, but that's generally frowned upon. Packages delivered via npm are designed to be "built", as in you use webpack, for example, to bring all the dependencies into one JS file, which you then also minimize. Then, you serve the generated file, rather than the "source" and all the dependencies individually.

[The ASP.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/) have some basic information of use, particularly concerning gulp and grunt. Webpack is a little more complex and not documented officially with ASP.NET Core, but it can be used just as well. Google is your friend here.

Comment: Well, yes and no. This is what *Microsoft's integration of bower* did for you. Out of the box, bower has its own `bower_modules` directory that would create the same problem. Microsoft customized the implementation so that everything would go into `wwwroot/lib` instead.

Comment: Thanks.  Sometimes my problem with searching is simply not knowing what to ask.  Now I do.

Comment: The gulp/grunt ASP.NET Core documention will give you the main ASP.NET Core specific parts, in terms of setting up build tasks and such. That's mostly the same no matter what you use. Then, if you want to use webpack, you just need to worry about how to properly set up your configuration for the most part.